# How to do a 301 redirect for a specific page across directories

Tags: .htaccess

I am having trouble getting a simple 301 redirect to work in a .htaccess file. I simply need to redirect a single old url to the new page. I've tried many variations but the code seems so simple that I can't think of any ideas as to why its not working. Its an Apache server, and I don't have access to the httpd.conf file. Other .htaccess configurations I have work fine, however I removed everything but the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

Redirect 301 /old-directory/old-page.php http://www.example.com/new-page.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the redirect clause really on two lines?

Put everything on one line:

```
Redirect 301 /old-directory/old-page.php http://www.example.com/new-page.php
```

Comment: I've tried it both ways, doesn't seem to make a difference though

Comment: Have you verified if there are errors in apache log? Maybe mod_rewrite is not even installed.

Comment: I will try look at the error log then. Although I've previously used the same .htaccess file to rewrite non-www to www addresses so I assumed it worked in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

`Redirect` directive is not from `mod_rewrite` module. Try this in **`/old-directory/.htaccess`**:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^old-page\.php$ http://www.example.com/new-page.php [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Tried this, both in a new .htaccess in the old directory and even in the root directory. Still doesn't work, so I've contacted my hosting provider to see if its a permissions issue

Comment: This rule will work from `/old-directory/.htaccess` only. To verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `/old-directory/.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Comment: It doesn't generate an error when I try that, so I guess I can't make .htaccess in sub directories?

Comment: You can have htaccess anywhere as long as server config allows it.